# Centering float items in <ul> and applying list-style-type

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, css-float

I am trying to display disc in nested ul items as image below

[image]

Now, the list-style-type is working but I don't know to center float element (`<li>`). One thing that with the first item, the disc appears above icon. You can see my site to clarify what I say. Thank all so much for helping me.

http://thehung.esy.es/Mozzarella/menu.html

**Update:** Fixed myself by using pseudo element for adding disc, thanks for all guys who voted this question down, let me can't post more questions :)

Comment: use pseudo element for adding disc

Comment: Please create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

Add one `div` outside of your ul element like below.

```
 <div style="text-align:center">
  <ul class="categories">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="box-icon">
                                <i class="circle-icon fa fa-android"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="tooltip">
                                <span>Facebook</span>
                            </div>  <!-- end tooltip -->
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="box-icon">
                            <a href="#"><i class="circle-icon fa fa-android"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="box-icon">
                            <a href="#"><i class="circle-icon fa fa-android"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="box-icon">
                            <a href="#"><i class="circle-icon fa fa-android"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="box-icon">
                            <a href="#"><i class="circle-icon fa fa-android"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="box-icon">
                            <a href="#"><i class="circle-icon fa fa-android"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
     </div>
```

Also update your `.categories` class like below.

```
 .categories
  {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto 70px;
    width: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know the disc of first item appears above its.